# Bluetooth scan delay results in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to build a bluetooth scanner in android. Using the following code I am able to generate a list of nearby bluetooth devices. But most of the times it takes `2-3 attempts` to find a device. Is this common or I am missing something? Why I didn't always get the device listed in 1st attempt?

## start discovering

```
bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovering()
```

## Broadcast receiver

```
if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
    BluetoothDevice device = -intentData.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    if(device != null) {
        //code to push in listview
    }
}
```

**Note: Other bluetooth device is definitely discover able.**

## Edit

I run my laptop's bluetooth discovery at the same time with android device. Laptop's bluetooth always find nearby device quickly, on the other hand android takes couple of attempt to find the same devices.